# NSPredicate using any search algorithm internally?

Tags: iphone, algorithm, search, nspredicate

Currently I am using NSPredicate to search from a string. But I have around 2000 records. So iterating through these records for search using NSPredicate take some time.

I just want to know whether NSPredicate using any search algorithm internally or should I use any search algorithm for fast searching ?

I want my app should search like contacts app (smoothly). What should I do so that my search will be smooth like contacts app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSPredicate` doesn't use *any* search algorithm - all `NSPredicate` does is represent your query.

It's the job of whatever accepts `NSPredicate` as a option to choose the search algorithm. In your case, it's probably `NSArray`'s `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` method?

If you want to search the data faster, you will have to write a better algorithm yourself, I bet the array just runs through each item and matches it to the predicate. Not efficient but it works for anything :)

Try looking at sqlite (or CoreData), they have better indexing than plain arrays.

Or you could make an index yourself - put each contact into a dictionary with the key being the first letter of the contact - that should reduce the amount of records you have to search!

i.e. instead of an array

```
[ @"Alex", @"Bob", @"Bill", @"Carl" ... ]
```

Have a dictionary

```
{
  @"A" : [ @"Alex" ],
  @"B" : [ @"Bob", @"Bill" ],
  @"C" : [ @"Carl" ] 
  ...
}
```

For the search string `@"Bi"` you only have to search through the items in the array for `@"B"`.

PS Don't forget to make your dictionary key case / diacritic independent ;)